# can css attribute matching be caseinsensitive ? with SASS?

Tags: javascript, css, sass, css-selectors

I'm formatting links depending on the kind of file they link to.

```
a[href$=".doc"] { background: url(icon-doc.png) left; padding-left: 30px; }
```

My problem is, attribute-matching seems to be case sensitive. Is it possible to have CSS match any case combinations?

Or is it possible to have compass/sass generating all the differing case variations? like

```
a[href$=".doc"], a[href$=".Doc"], a[href$=".dOc"] { ... }
```

Or do I need to make some js to lowercase all attributes?

Comment: Selectors 4 will allow you to force an attribute selector to match case-insensitively, using `a[href$=".doc" i]`. No word on implementations yet, but it should be easy enough for browser makers to do once they get around to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was harder than i thought but i'm too stubborn to quit :P

```scss
$ext-s : ("gif", "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "project");

@function to-upper-case-at($s, $n) {
    @if $n < 1 {
        @return $s;
    }
    @if str-length($s) == 1 {
        @return to-upper-case($s);
    }
    $before : "";
    $after : "";
    $char: "";
    @if $n > 1 {
        $before : str-slice($s, 1, $n - 1); 
    }
    @if $n < str-length($s) {
        $after : str-slice($s, $n + 1); 
    }
    $char: to-upper-case(str-slice($s, $n, $n));
    @return $before + $char + $after;   
}

@function power ($x, $n) {
    $ret: 1;

    @if $n >= 0 {
        @for $i from 1 through $n {
            $ret: $ret * $x;
        } 
    } @else {
        @for $i from $n to 0 {
            $ret: $ret / $x;
        }
    }

    @return $ret;
}

@function bin-mask-list($dec-int) {
    $r : $dec-int;
    $res : ();
    $dig : 0;
    $last : false;
    @while $last == false {
        $m : $r % 2;
        @if $m != 0 {
            $dig : 1;
        }
        @else {
            $dig : 0;
        }
        $res : join($dig, $res);
        @if ($r == 1) or ($r == 0) {
            $last : true;
        } 
        $r : floor($r / 2);
    }
    @return $res;  
}

@function all-cases($string) {
    $case-list: ($string);
    $length : str-length($string);

    @for  $i from 1 to power(2, $length) {
        $mask : bin-mask-list($i);
        $res-string : $string;
        @while $length > length($mask) {
            $mask : join(0, $mask); 
        }
        @for  $j from 1 through $length {
            $digit : nth($mask, $j);
            @if $digit == 1{
                 $res-string : to-upper-case-at($res-string, $j);
            }
        }
        $case-list : append($case-list, $res-string);
    }
    @return $case-list;
}

@each $ext in $ext-s {
  $all-c : all-cases($ext);
  @each $c in $all-c {
    a[href$=".#{$c}"] { background: url(icon-doc.#{$c}) left; padding-left: 30px; }
  }
}
```

It will output around 2k lines of css like this one:

```css
/* line 85, ../scss/test.scss */
a[href$=".gif"] {
  background: url(icon-doc.gif) left;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

/* line 85, ../scss/test.scss */
a[href$=".giF"] {
  background: url(icon-doc.giF) left;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

/* line 85, ../scss/test.scss */
a[href$=".gIf"] {
  background: url(icon-doc.gIf) left;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

/* line 85, ../scss/test.scss */
a[href$=".gIF"] {
  background: url(icon-doc.gIF) left;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

/* line 85, ../scss/test.scss */
a[href$=".Gif"] {
  background: url(icon-doc.Gif) left;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

/* line 85, ../scss/test.scss */
a[href$=".GiF"] {
  background: url(icon-doc.GiF) left;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

/* line 85, ../scss/test.scss */
a[href$=".GIf"] {
  background: url(icon-doc.GIf) left;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

/* line 85, ../scss/test.scss */
a[href$=".GIF"] {
  background: url(icon-doc.GIF) left;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

/* line 85, ../scss/test.scss */
a[href$=".jpg"] {
  background: url(icon-doc.jpg) left;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: that is an awsome solution  :)   thanx

Comment: This is an impressive technical solution, but I think 2000 lines of CSS is waaaaay too much bloat for something like case insensitivity that should really be handled server side.

Comment: @KatieK Well if you use it to generate selector list for a couple of short extensions and minify then it won't be too heavy. But yes it has potential to explode so i wont recommend using it in implicit way or as part of a lib.  It's the last resort solution.

Answer (score 0):

URLs are all case sensitive, so yes, you need to make your links consistent.
[CSS file name case sensitivity & Css file caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614226/css-file-name-case-sensitivity-css-file-caching)

Comment: While it's true that URLs are case-sensitive, it has nothing to do with the question at hand, which is about CSS attribute selector matching.

Comment: yes ... but uploaded files can have all kinds of upper and lower case - and if they are on other systems than mine, I can't control their case.